# How do I render a div and script tags in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-react-parser

The react application received a visualization code, and I used the unescape function to get the HTML codes in string. The string has a `div` tag with the id of the visualization and `script` tag that consists of the javascript to generate the visualization.

```
import React from "react";
import parse from "html-react-parser";

export default function App() {
  // This code is received from the backend
  const vizCode =
    "%3Cdiv%20id%3D'chartdiv_1614071920146'%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3Cscript%20type%3D'text%2Fjavascript'%3E%20var%20width_1614071920146%20%3D%20700%3Bvar%20height_1614071920146%20%3D%20700%3Bvar%20chart_1614071920146%20%3D%20c3.generate(%7Bbindto%3A%20'%23chartdiv_1614071920146'%2C%20size%3A%20%7B%20width%3A%20(width_1614071920146%20-%2020)%2C%20height%3A%20(height_1614071920146%20-%2020)%20%7D%2C%20data%3A%20%7Bcolumns%3A%20%5B%20%5B'%20'%2C%201.0%2C%201.0%2C%203.0%2C%205.0%2C%205.0%5D%20%5D%2C%20type%3A%20'spline'%7D%2C%20legend%3A%20%7Bshow%3Afalse%7D%2C%20axis%3A%20%7B%20x%3A%20%7B%20type%3A%20'category'%2C%20categories%3A%20%5B'New%20Course'%2C'group%20course%201'%2C'Testkurs%20'%2C'test_course'%2C'Moodle4CollaborativeMOOCs'%5D%20%7D%20%7D%7D)%3B%3C%2Fscript%3E";
  const unescapedVizCode = unescape(vizCode);
  console.log(unescapedVizCode);
  // Output -> <div id='chartdiv_1614071920146'></div><script type='text/javascript'> var width_1614071920146 = 700;var height_1614071920146 = 700;var chart_1614071920146 = c3.generate({bindto: '#chartdiv_1614071920146', size: { width: (width_1614071920146 - 20), height: (height_1614071920146 - 20) }, data: {columns: [ [' ', 1.0, 1.0, 3.0, 5.0, 5.0] ], type: 'spline'}, legend: {show:false}, axis: { x: { type: 'category', categories: ['New Course','group course 1','Testkurs ','test_course','Moodle4CollaborativeMOOCs'] } }});</script> 

  let objectData = parse(unescapedVizCode);
  let divData = objectData[0];
  let scriptData = objectData[1].props.dangerouslySetInnerHTML.__html;

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {objectData}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here I have provided the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/render-c3d3-charts-in-react-zc378?file=/src/App.js:1188-1204) link

I used the `dangerouslySetInnerHtml` to display the visualization but unable to visualize the chart. I have added a test.html in the public folder to show the visualization in a browser. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React/JSX doesn't deal with script tags.
You have to explicitly load it.
I'd suggest you use a hook when the component is available.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.innerHTML = scriptData;
    document.getElementById('root').appendChild(script);
    return () => {
      document.getElementById('root').removeChild(script);
    };
  }, []);
```

Working example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/render-c3d3-charts-in-react-forked-4xkt9?file=/src/App.js

btw. Please don't use 'unescape', it is deprecated. Use 'decodeURIComponent' instead.

Answer (score 1):

Okay this answer does what you want, but I have to say: Only use this if you know 100% where the vizCode comes from and that it can be trusted! [be sure to check out the reasons why you should not use eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#never_use_eval!)

Your problem is, that the script content is not being executed by the browser. I tried your sandbox and it immediately worked when I added

```
eval(scriptData)
```

Here's the entire code that's working for me:

```
export default function App() {
  // This code is received from the backend
  const vizCode =
    "%3Cdiv%20id%3D'chartdiv_1614071920146'%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3Cscript%20type%3D'text%2Fjavascript'%3E%20var%20width_1614071920146%20%3D%20700%3Bvar%20height_1614071920146%20%3D%20700%3Bvar%20chart_1614071920146%20%3D%20c3.generate(%7Bbindto%3A%20'%23chartdiv_1614071920146'%2C%20size%3A%20%7B%20width%3A%20(width_1614071920146%20-%2020)%2C%20height%3A%20(height_1614071920146%20-%2020)%20%7D%2C%20data%3A%20%7Bcolumns%3A%20%5B%20%5B'%20'%2C%201.0%2C%201.0%2C%203.0%2C%205.0%2C%205.0%5D%20%5D%2C%20type%3A%20'spline'%7D%2C%20legend%3A%20%7Bshow%3Afalse%7D%2C%20axis%3A%20%7B%20x%3A%20%7B%20type%3A%20'category'%2C%20categories%3A%20%5B'New%20Course'%2C'group%20course%201'%2C'Testkurs%20'%2C'test_course'%2C'Moodle4CollaborativeMOOCs'%5D%20%7D%20%7D%7D)%3B%3C%2Fscript%3E";
  const unescapedVizCode = unescape(vizCode);
  console.log(unescapedVizCode);

  let objectData = parse(unescapedVizCode);
  let divData = objectData[0];
  let scriptData = objectData[1].props.dangerouslySetInnerHTML.__html;
  useEffect(()=>{
    eval(scriptData)
  }, [scriptData])
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {objectData}

    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it satisfies your requirement, but you can use `window.open` to render the HTML code within `iFrame` or in a new tab.

To open in `iFrame` use the following code:

```
const unescapedVizCode = unescape(vizCode);
window.open(unescapedVizCode, "myFrame");
return (
<div className="App">
<iframe name="myFrame"></iframe>
  {objectData}
</div>
);
```

Or you can open in new tab:

```
const unescapedVizCode = unescape(vizCode);
window.open(unescapedVizCode, "_blank");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
let objectData = parse(`<div className="App">${unescapedVizCode}</div>`);

return objectData;
```